# Need to set base href without a base tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to set the base href of my Angular application without the html tag.

Normally, i'll do something like:

```
 <base href='myBaseUrl' />
```

But my whole app is being added within another MVC application. The MVC app references my app by calling it from an hosting CDN this way:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- ... -->
      <link href="https://www.host.com/myApp.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- MVC stuff -->
      <div ng-app="app" class="theContainerHoldingMyWholeApp">
         <my-component></my-component>
      </div>
      <!-- Other MVC stuff -->
      <script href="https://www.host.com/myApp.min.js" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to add a base tag in the head in order to make my app templates loading work. There is no routing in the app. But if i do, it breaks all relatives paths that were already in my old MVC app. The only way I can think of is by somehow setting the "baseHref" using javascript, but i didn't find anything about it in Angular docs.

So, I'm wondering, is there anyone who sucessfully set the Angular base href WITHOUT having a `<base />` in it's page. I'm willing to use unsupported stuff if I have to.